# What is "VDCI" in terms of output voltage?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I am trying to bring back an old monochrome plasma screen from the dead.  I have little information on the device, its from a Compaq Portable (Luggable) III PC.  The manual for the unit lists power supply output specs as follows:
+5.0 VDC
+12.0 VDC
-12.0VDC
+200VDCI
5.0VDCI

That is exactly whats printed in the manual (minus a few columns about min. current, avg. current, and tolerance), not sure why the one "5VDCI" line doesn't have a "+" in front of it.

But more importantly, I have no idea what "VDCI" means.  Is this some old notation (the manual has 1987 as a first print date)? Is this just a typo? Is it some term I have never heard of before? Or is it absolutely nothing at all and simply means volts DC?

Alternatively, if someone manages to hunt down operating specs of the LCD in there, that would be just as awesome.  I've put many hours in to figuring out what I have thus far.

Answer (score 1):

From a bit of Googling, it seems that this is terminology used in voltage source devices to mean V<sub>DC</sub> from an inverter. I'd guess that the lack of a + in front of the 5.0V is just a typo.

That being said, it may also be that they OCR'ed the data from a PDF, and it mistook a close-bracket as an 'I', i.e. "Something (+200VDC)" became "Something +200VDCI".

Comment: Can you provide any links that would suggest this?  I have since spent a good amount of time searching for this link and have found nothing.